# iOS Storyboard intro view followed by table view with core data

Tags: core-data, storyboard

I'm using a storyboard with an initial intro view controller that I want to segue to a table view controller with core data.  I understand that the initial controller is the root controller but I need the 2nd controller to be the root because of connecting to core data.  When I do the following in my app delegate, I get this error:

```
-[IntroViewController setViewControllers:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7465b70
2013-01-21 22:29:15.331 PManager[35522:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[IntroViewController setViewControllers:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7465b70'
```

My first view is called "introController" in the storyboard.

My second view is a table view hooked to core data called "listController" in the storyboard.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options
{

    // Get a reference to the navigation controller first
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;

    IntroViewController *introController = [navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"introController"];
    RootViewController *listController = [navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"listController"];

    // First item in array is bottom of stack, last item is top.
    navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:listController, introController, nil];

    // THEN get the root view controller (RootViewController)
    RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    // And now pass the context
    rootViewController.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that you need to pass the managedObjectContext to the second view controller? Because when using Storyboards you don't usually mess around with the initial view controllers there, you let the storyboard handle it.

Comment: Yes, and when you reference the rootViewController - storyboard assumes this is the intro controller.

Comment: In that case, you probably just need to change the way your app is organised. INstead of relying on the app delegate class to manage the managedObjectContext, create another class to do it and reference that class directly from your table view controller class. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350915/most-efficient-way-of-passing-data-between-views/14351026#14351026

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I created a CoreDataHelper class and tried to access the saveContext method from within the applicationWillTerminate method of the app delegate with this:   [[CoreDataHelper coreDataHelper] saveContext];  However, I receive an error "No known class method for selector 'coreDataHelper'  I think this is because my method needs to begin with a + but when I do that, I get the error:  "Instance variable 'managedObjectContext' access in class method.  I'm not familiar with working with class methods.  Sorry to ask so many questions!

Comment: I formulated a new question with some screen shots:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471331/how-do-i-create-a-coredatahelper-class-to-contain-core-data-methods-instead-of-u)

Comment: OK, cool, and already answered I see! I've rewritten my comment as an answer so if it works out don't forget to return here and assign some points for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better to change the way your app is organised. Instead of relying on the app delegate class to manage the `managedObjectContext`, create another class, as a singleton, to 
manage access to your managed object context globally. Reference that class directly from your table view controller class and any others. Something like this: [Most efficient way of passing data between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350915/most-efficient-way-of-passing-data-between-views/14351026#14351026)